# How to get every sentence enclose by tag in beautifulsoup( Not only text but also html tags etc / Python)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get `Orange` and `1p` from below sample `HTML`.

I can get gather sentence like `Orange1p` but can not get 2 sentence separately.

Any way to get 2 sentence?

sample `HTML`:

```html
<td class="info">Orange<br/>1p</td>
```

Current used code :

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("td", {"class": "info"}) # with current output of `Orange1p`
```

Comment: have you parsed html with beautiful soup?

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't mention that. I revised my question. Thanks your comment!

Comment: Can you also provide some more <td> tags example

Comment: @Himanshu the `OP` were clear enough on the provided example.

Comment: Awesome! My problem solved!! Thank you so much both of you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """<td class="info">Orange<br/>1p</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(list(soup.find("td", {'class': 'info'}).strings))
```

Output:

```
['Orange', '1p']
```